# What term should i use to describe the taste intensity of a crop?

Tags: flavor

I am making a questionnaire about food and one of things people can rate is the taste intensity or taste strength of a vegetable/fruit/nut etc. Right now i just call it taste intensity and people can rate it from 1 to 10. Strawberry has a very rich taste so i would probably give that a high taste intensity score whereas a cucumber tastes very watery so i would give it a low score.

So is there a term that describes 'taste intensity'?

Edit: This is my full rating survey.

[image]

Comment: hi, i have other tastes people can rate. Please see the picture i've added. Its a survey for a gardener website i'm making

Comment: It possible that different people perceive the intensity of flavors differently.  Your "rich tasting strawberry" might not taste so rich to me.  What are you trying to learn by surveying gardeners?

Comment: yes but on average people will agree that a strawberry tastes less sour then an orange right?

Comment: also, its a opinion based survey, the whole idea is to give a representation of how sweet people rate a particular strawberry on average for example

Comment: Your taste intensity is like the thickness of the soup/broth?

Comment: no its how strong the taste is, for example cucumber hardly tastes like anything (very mild watery taste) whereas radish has a very strong flavor. Maybe i should just call it flavor strength? @Cindy

Comment: @Conifers see my previous post

Comment: I think it is very difficult to rate flavour intensity of a food on a scale, and even more to compare the answers from different people, as they will set the scale differently in their heads. So I might rate a strawberry to be a 6, while you might rate it 8, even though we experience the same taste. I think a better approach would be to ask people to rank different fruits/vegetables, so you have a relative rating instead of an absolute one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "Flavour Intensity"

Answer (score 0):

Another term that comes to mind is flavor pungency which can possibly substitute "flavor strength" and it works synonymically with taste intensity.

Comment: isnt pungency the same as spicyness? According to the dictionary pungency is saying how hot a food is

Comment: It can be interpreted that way. Perhaps it is best to stick to taste intensity so it can't be applied to any specific such as spiciness.